getting "You are not permitted to use OAuth2 on this endpoint" in twitter v2 api
postman image
I am getting this error when I want to access all from of twitter user from userid
{
    "title": "Forbidden",
    "type": "about:blank",
    "status": 403,
    "detail": "You are not permitted to use OAuth2 on this endpoint"
}

I am passing accesstoken via bearer token
I am sending request on this endpoint https://api.twitter.com/2/users/:id/tweets to get user posts but getting error. To see the error please view attached image.
please someone help me how can I resolve this error
